no windowmanager to choose from shown on loginscreen - no login possible after failed pythin install
after I installed and removed python the kubuntu login screen changed, i cannot choose a windowmanager on dropdown menu the  as nothing shown on the dropdownmenu on lockscreen, and pressing enter after entering password does nothing, basically i cannot login anymore.
I have access to a different gnome installation on the same laptop but no login into the first kubuntu installation is possible

Your description is too vague. Unless you pprovide precise details about your Ubuntu version and what you exactly did, I can only suggest to reinstall the OS.

You are aware that Ubuntu desktop systems have many tools/components that rely on the default python3 version, and if its removed or version changed; those features will stop working (or worse may continue to work incorrectly which can result in corruption).  You give few specifics; but do not change the default python3 version or remove it.

its the 20.04 - installed python to run a programm via synaptic and removed it. i don't want to lose all customizations and all files !

Ubuntu Desktop systems (including flavors like Kubuntu) come with python3 pre-installed; so your details are incomplete; as attempting to install the same version of python3 would just report it was already installed; however the system will let you install multiple different versions; and you can remove all but the default version of python3 without problems, however you've not been specific with details.  What exactly did you install?  Did it install or report it was already installed??  What exactly did you remove? as details matter.  Read your apt logs to be sure.

You mention Kubuntu in your title; Kubuntu 20.04 LTS had 3 years of supported life (see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes/Kubuntu) which ended April 2023.  Your question if about 20.04 is still on-topic here, as Ubuntu 20.04 LTS comes with 5 years of standard support, and you can use KDE Plasma on that; but Kubuntu 20.04 LTS is End of Life.

i thought all this would cause no problems - when I rebooted the login screen had changed and a dropdownmenu of window managers (like xfce, etc etc kde, I assume) is blank and I cannot chose  -- and if i enter the pwd, enter key doesnt confirm the input, so i cannot login anymore

This is a Question and Answer site so details belong in your question. Your question still doesn't give specifics; no Ubuntu release; no python3 install/removal version details etc...  Many GUI features require the default python3 to be installed & working to work; and will stop working (or not work correctly) if python3 version is changed or removed.. Text logins should still work (ie. Ctrl+Alt+F4 and login to text terminal) which allow you to explore & fix issues; but GUI features will require you to re-install or correct default python3 version to what is correct for your release.

apologies, basically I cannot go past the broken login screen of kubuntu 20.04 anymore. please tell me which command and output you need or how i can repair the python install while not being able to go past login screen..seems like I made the error when trying to remove the additional python installation and this is the cause. thanks a lot for  the support so far.

If you damaged  (including changed version) the default version of python3 on your system, your GUI is broken. You must login to text terminal and fix the issue there (ie. Ctrl+Alt+F4 and login there as I've already stated).  I don't what you've done, as you've not been specific; but you need to ensure any/all changes to default python3 version get reverted (ask whomever changed it for clues as to what was done) and ensure python3-minimal is installed (3.8.2-0ubuntu2) which will cause your system to have & update to the correct python3 for your system..

Once you have the correct python3-minimal installed (and have it running, not another version) you should be able to use normal apt or apt-get commands to fix the rest (to get python3-minimal installed you may need to use simple wget to download & dpkg -i to install; why re-install or restoring backups is easier). Once correct python3 is installed/running, you can usually just read output of commands & follow instructions to fix problems (but what to do then will be revealed anyway via command output/messages)

thanks so much - how can i get into terminal shell from the (not working) login screen - i will try ctl alt f4 again - and please sry for being not knowledgable - how can I repair and revert changes from commandline ? thanks so much!
